# Javascript console.log errors: how to see the real object of the Error

Tags: javascript, console.log

When console.logging errors, the browser prints a differently styled output than if it were a normal object. How can you force Google / Firefox to print the real object of the Error class instead of the stylized less useful 'error' output?

I know for example the object contains `e.message` and `e.response` for example, which you can never deduct from the Browsers log outputs.

```
api
  .post('/post/create', formData)
  .then((res) => {
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    // doesn't print the error object
    // doesn't print the error object
    // doesn't print the error object
    console.log(e)

    // UPDATE, destructuring does print the full Error object
    // UPDATE, destructuring does print the full Error object
    // UPDATE, destructuring does print the full Error object
    console.log('full error object', {e})
  })
```

[image: Firefox]
[image: Chrome]

**Update after approved answer.** Now I got the full error object.

[image]

Comment: Why doesn't the stack trace help?

Comment: You made a request. The server responded with 401. So check the request/response in the network tab and/or the server.

Comment: And the browser cannot show your server node code

Comment: I just want the underlying error object, which it refuses to print.

Comment: You won't get any relevant information on the client about a problem on the server. If you send information about the problem with the response then you shouldn't use an error response code (4xx, 5xx).

Comment: It does show the error object. The error of the fetch request.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simple solution - log the error object as a property of a plain object

```
try {
    throw Error("Some error text");
}
catch( error) {
    console.log( {error});
}
```

This allows you to inspect and expand the structure of an error object in the same way you would any other. Best performed in a browser since code snippets don't provide inspection facilities.

Comment: Thanks. Now I'm getting the full error object printed as a regular object. I guess I'm of the few ones that actually finds this useful? There is a lot of useful props in that Error object.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in this scenario:

`
#!/usr/bin/node

function main() {
    try {
        const myArgs = process.argv.slice(2);
        const fs = require('fs')
        fs.readFile(myArgs[0], (inputD) => {
            console.log(inputD.toString());
        })
    } catch (error) {
        console.log({error})
    }
}

main();
`

Comment: @StenTechy `fs.readFile` doesn't throw, so there is no error to catch. Try re-writing the callback to expect two arguments. The first one, `error`, will be null if the read was successful. See [node docs](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) for details.

Comment: @traktor passing an incorrect file name throws an error.

Comment: @StenTechy My misunderstanding: the catch block does receive the synchronous error generated for an invalid argument passed to `readFile`. Unfortunately the node Error object does not appear to have enumerable properties except for 'code', and the only non enumerable properties I could guess at were 'message' and 'stack`, which are already included in console output. Given the node console does **not** have inspection facilities, additional information may be difficult to obtain - please ask a new question if you want a wider response regarding node.